# Limitation submisson on webform hide my form

Tags: webforms, 9

I've created a form with webform and configured the submission limit, however when I test when arriving at the submission limit, the form is hidden : Nothing is displayed, As if there were no form at this location, whereas from what I've understood on tutorials, I'm still supposed to access the form with an error displayed on submission.

what could be the reason for this behavior, is it a setting?

thanks

Comment: What does "hidden" mean, technically? Which tutorials?

Comment: @cilefen It mean the form isn't displayed.
For the tutorial, I followed this youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdkv10v3AX4&ab_channel=JacobRockowitz

Comment: That information should be added to the Question. What is displayed instead of the form?

Comment: @cilefen Nothing is displayed, As if there were no form at this location

Comment: The entire page is a white space with no content whatsoever. Do I have that right?

Comment: @cilefen Only the form is no longer displayed, the other blocks are displayed correctly.